# Upload rolling files to Azure Blob

Tags: azure, powershell-2.0, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to foresee a system where tweets are flowing to Azure Blob storage through the Twitter streaming API. I was following a tutorial from Microsoft but it ends in a following scenario:

```
$writeStream = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter $memStream
$count=0
$lineMax=1000000
$sReader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($response.GetResponseStream())


$inrec = $sReader.ReadLine()

while (($inrec -ne $null) -and ($count -le $lineMax))
{
    if ($inrec -ne "")
    {
        $writeStream.WriteLine($inrec)
    }




    $inrec=$sReader.ReadLine()
}


$writeStream.Flush()
$memStream.Seek(0, "Begin")
$destBlob.UploadFromStream($memStream)

$sReader.close()
```

Now the problem is, if I want to use this on large scale I suspect the file will become too big to be sent to Azure in one go. What is the correct approach for this problem? Should I roll the files locally to disk and then send it to Azure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check out the new Append Blob. This lets you create a blob and keep appending to it (from multiple locations if needed). Here's some [how-to information](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/#writing-to-an-append-blob) that may help.

Comment: Thanks Robin, very nice! Reading the article I see that the maximum size of and append blob is about 195 Gb. When it gets full, is there a mechanism available to start a new blob automatically or should I take care of this myself in the code? 
Also, for HDFS I know the block size is about 64Mb. Do you know the reason behind taking 4Mb here as the block size for an append blob? Will it not drastically increase the number of seeks when retrieving the data? Or can't I make the comparison between HDFS and Azure Blob storage this way.

Comment: I think you have to handle the size yourself. Maybe you should consider figuring out how long it takes on average to hit that size, then every X hours, create a new blob. I don't think you can compare HDFS and Azure Blob Storage, it's like apples and oranges. You *could* stage the files locally and then move them to blob storage (in a separate process). Just be sure the files aren't too large to read/process by whatever is going to read/process them. If running the processing of the twitter feed in an Azure VM, you could use premium storage for data disks to maximize the IOPS and speed.